# Different outputs based on responses to multiple questions (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a questionnaire where it asks multiple yes/no questions, and after receiving all of the responses a different output is shown depending on the combination of answers provided.

For example, if there were three questions and someone answered no, no, then yes, they would see one output (just a simple sentence that I will create), but if someone else answered yes, no, yes, they would see a different response at the end. I don't want to provide feedback after each individual question, only when all questions have been answered.

I was trying to use if/else, but that didn't seem to be working for my purposes (at least the way I was doing it, but I am very new to Python!). I'm sorry that I don't have much to work with, but I am trying to learn and have been doing Google search after Google search to no avail. Thank you!!

EDIT: Here's what I've been trying. Is there any way to extend on this? What I've done is based on my limited knowledge of Python.

```
female = raw_input("Are you female?")
over18 = raw_input("Are you over 18?")
shopping = raw_input("Do you like to go shopping?")
```

And then I know how to do something like

```
if female=="yes":
    print "blahblah"
else:
    print "something else"
```

But I don't know how to use all three responses to contribute to what will print. I also can't figure out how to restrict each question to just a yes/no answer.

EDIT 2:

Can I use multiple if statements as shown below? I know how to use just one response to change the output, but having three influence just one output is just throwing me for a loop.

```
female = raw_input("Are you female?")
over18 = raw_input("Are you over 18?")
shopping = raw_input("Do you like to go shopping?")
if (female=="yes" and over18=="yes" and shopping=="yes"):
    print "1"
if (female=="yes" and over18=="yes" and shopping=="no"):
    print "2"
if (female=="yes" and over18=="no" and shopping=="no"):
    print "3"
if (female=="yes" and over18=="no" and shopping=="yes"):
    print "4"
if (female=="no" and over18=="yes" and shopping=="yes"):
    print "5"
if (female=="no" and over18=="yes" and shopping=="no"):
    print "6"
if (female=="no" and over18=="no" and shopping=="yes"):
    print "7"
if (female=="no" and over18=="no" and shopping=="no"):
    print "8"
else:
    print "invalid"
```

It looks like that is functioning relatively well, but no matter what combination of "yes" and "no" I use it will give me the correct number output but then also say "invalid." However, if I take out the else, it won't restrict the answers to "yes" or "no," will it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you have an example that wasn't working, please post it (edit your post) so we can help you with a specific problem.  As it is written, there are likely an infinite number of ways to accomplish what you've asked, but with a code sample, this will be manageable.

Comment: If you know how `if/else` statement works and you know how to store answers you should be able to do this. Drawing on paper logical structure you intend to implement can be very helpful.

Comment: I do not know how to store answers actually! I think that's my problem

Comment: You *are* storing answers: in `female`, `over18` and `shopping` names. Now you need to put them in logical conditions (`if/else` statements). You've made your first step - you've put one name (`female`) in a condition. Now you need to put all three names in `if/else` statements. You can use logical operators. See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/logical_operators_example.htm) for examples. Answer using dictionaries (given by @Noufal Ibrahim) is also a good option.

Comment: You can see how error prone the if/else approach is. Do consider using a data structure to store your results rather than coding them in.

Comment: If you will stick with if-method (rather than one given by Noufal Ibrahim, which I urge you to try) you should use `if/elif/else` rather than `if/else'. It would look like this `if` ... `elif` ... `elif`... `elif`... `elif`...`else`. After the last statement (else) you would have the invalid case. See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm).

Comment: I've updated my answer with something that works so that you can try it out.

Answer (score 3):

One way that occurs to me is to make a dictionary keyed by a tuple of yes/no responses - one for each question. So if you have, say, 2 questions - 1 and 2, you'd have 4 possible outcomes. YY, YN, NY, and NN. You can create a dictionary with keys that correspond to these. So something like

```
def ask_question(qn):
    resp = raw_input(qn)
    if resp.lower() in ["yes", "y"]: # Handles Yes, yes etc.
        return True
    else:
        return False

responses = {(True, True) : "Old Male",
             (True, False) : "Young Male",
             (False, True) : "Old Female",
             (False, False) : "Young Female"}

answers = []
questions = ["Are you male?", "Are you over 18?"]
for q in questions:
   answers.append(ask_question(q))

print responses[tuple(answers)]
```

Since the actual answers are in data (rather than code), you can read these out from a file which you can edit/generate easily. It's a much more conventient way of mananging than a huge and hairy if/elif/else block.